# Decrypt DES accepts some keys variation of the real key

Tags: java, des

I am using DES method. When I try to decrypt, it accepts variation of the real key.

For example:

```
Real key: abcdefgh
Key 1: accefgh
key 2: abcdefgi
```

Those keys( key 1 and key2) are accepted when I decrypt, even though those ones are not the real key that I used to encrypt. What I have figured out is that those variations are accepted.

Look at the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkMbE.png)

Why does the method DES accept these variation of the key that I used to encrypt?

Comment: Interesting picture.  Here's a picture of my car, marked up with some different colors of paint.  It won't start. Please tell me why.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in the least.

Comment: What is the matter with the picture?

Comment: Well, the drawing of the picture lead to an extrapolation of A-Z which is not correct.

Comment: @zaph 
you are right, I have just fixed it

Comment: @JimGarrison Flux capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

The least significant bit of each byte in a DES key is a 'parity' bit that doesn't really influence the cipher.

It's a little hard to say from your example whether this is what you're seeing, but the ASCII values of the characters 'B' and 'C' differ only in the LSb.  Same for 'D' and 'E', 'F' and 'G', etc.  Only 'Z'/'A' breaks the pattern.

Comment: I suspect the Z-A was just added to make the picture neat.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b You are right, The A-Z doesn't fit, but the others do, I tried whit a key built by numbers: 123456789 and when I tried with some variations like 113456789 or 12145678, those variations are being accepted, is it supposed that the key is unique?

Comment: I think it would be a useful exercise for you to do the following:
Take the strings you are supplying as the DES keys, and look up each character in an ASCII table, to see the byte each character represents.  Then, write the binary representation of each byte.  I think you will find that, for every 'variant' that works, it only differs from the original key in the LSb of each byte.  This is a known behavior of DES.

Comment: Look at the binary of ASCII representation[Wikipedia ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Notice the lsb (least significant bit), the one on the right. Notice how it changes A-B, C-D, etc. This bit is ignored by DES. B is 0x421, C is 0x43, if the lsb of C is ignored, that is taken to by 0 than C becomed B.

Comment: I always find that lack of knowledge of binary and ASCII encoding strange because I deft with that on day I started coding, we all had to know that Times have changes, conceptual levels have moved up and for most development that does not need to be known. Encryption is an exception, it is binary based.

Comment: I've read both responses,DES ignores the lsb of each byte, the accepted variations reduces the security, so the only solution is to use another method?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then yes.  DES cannot be made stronger than an effective 56-bit key-strength, even though it takes a 64-bit key.  If you need to use DES, consider triple-DES (a.k.a 3DES, TDES, TDEA, and DESede)

Comment: It is weird,the  56 bit-key-strenght or 8 size String is not a matter for little projects, the real matter is that it doesn't consider the LSB, it makes the key not unique, I have to look for other method, thank you so much for help

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b DES takes a 56-bit key in 8-bytes.

Comment: @WalterFredyHuanacoHuayta Use AES, DES has been superseded by AES. **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).

Answer (score 0):

DES takes a 64 bit key but only actually uses 56 bits. The remaining 8 bits are discarded or used for parity checking.

Comment: Close, DES takes an 8-byte key and the lsb of each byte is not part of the key and discarded. The lsb was initially for parity.